# dplyr summarise won't work when I get column name from list?

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I am creating a shiny app and using user input to create graphs. The pipe and graph works when I specifically name the column in the pipe like :

```
f <- fb_ad %>%
  filter(geo == d_choices[2]) %>% 
  group_by(ad_name) %>% 
  summarise(n = sum(clicks))
```

But it doesn't work when I use a list that contains the column names/the user input and then access an element of the list through the pipe like so:

```
ycol <- c("impressions","reach", "clicks",
             "age", "gender")

f <- fb_ad %>%
   filter(geo == d_choices[2]) %>% 
   group_by(ad_name) %>% 
   summarise(n = sum(ycol[3]))
```

I get the error:

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
   Evaluation error: invalid 'type' (character) of argument.
```

Why doesn't that work and how can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the latest version of dplyr, as well as the rlang package installed, you can use:

```
f <- fb_ad %>%
filter(geo == d_choices[2]) %>% 
group_by(ad_name) %>% 
summarise(n = sum(!!rlang::sym(ycol[3])))
```

A mini working example of this principle (for others that do not have your data) would be:

```
library(tidyverse)
ddf <- 
  data.frame(X = rnorm(5), Y = rnorm(5), A = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B")) %>% 
  tbl_df() %>% mutate(A = as.character(A))

Ch <- c("X", "Y")

ddf %>% group_by(A) %>% 
summarise(N := sum(!!rlang::sym(Ch[2])))
```

Comment: The !! (aka bang-bang) notation is useful. You can find info about it by searching for "dplyr bang bang" (since most search engines won't handle a search for !!).

Answer (score 0):

This is a place where `summarise_at()` is useful, since the `_at` variant directly supports strings.

Any variables to summarize can be passed directly as strings and the summarizing function can be passed by name.  If you want to rename the output column you can put the function inside `funs()`.

Here is what the code could look like for your example:

```
fb_ad %>%
     filter(geo == d_choices[2]) %>% 
     group_by(ad_name) %>% 
     summarise_at(ycol[3], funs(n = sum) )
```